# Docker build-arg and copy

Tags: docker

Trying to copy a folders content, it works when i hard code the path like:

```
COPY ./my-folder /path/to/location
```

But need to be able to change this path so i tried using a build argument like this:

```
COPY ${folderVariable} /path/to/location
```

and then build with

```
--build-arg folderVariable=./my-folder
```

But it copies everything in the same folder as "my-folder", when i only want the contents of "my-folder"

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You need to define it with `ARG` in `Dockerfile` before using:

```
FROM alpine:3.3

ARG folderVariable=./my-folder # Optional default value to be `./my-folder`

COPY ${folderVariable} /opt/my-folder
```

And build it like:

```
docker build --build-arg folderVariable=./folder-copy -t test .
```

More details please refer to: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg

Comment: This might have worked previously, but with current docker version (19.03.4) the build argument does not seem to expand as expected.

Comment: @Emil, do you have a multi-stage build? [`ARG` is scoped to the build stage.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#scope)

Comment: Does not appear to expand in a COPY statement's --from argument in a single-stage build (in 19.03.5 or in 18).

Comment: Beware, `ARG` has scope (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#scope). I've been struggling for hours :P

Comment: I had same issue, i updated docker, move the ARG to be after the FORM, then I also see that my ARG had leading space, and it bothered the copy command.

Comment: Holy crap @Manolo wish I had found your comment 4 hours ago... The scoping thing is not very intuitive imo

Comment: @Manolo thank you so much! I didn't realize that the image I was pulling in my `FROM` was _also_ doing a multi-stage build and changing the scope. Your comment and link helped me solve this!

Answer (score 72):

Expansion still does not work for the `COPY --from=$var ...` case.
But you can create intermediate image as an alias, like this:

```
ARG docsBranch=4.5
ARG docsFullPath=registry.myCompany.pro/group/project-docs/docs:$docsBranch

# Lifehack
FROM $docsFullPath as docs

FROM node:10.21.0-buster-slim
WORKDIR /app

# Now we can use docs instead of $docsFullPath
COPY --from=docs /app/html/en ./documentation/en
```

Comment: you can even give full image name instead of just version number. As in given example following would also work:  
`ARG docsImageName=registry.myCompany.pro/group/project-docs/docs:0.1`  
`ARG docsFullPath=$docsImageName`

Comment: Still a problem in 2022. This should be the right answer.