# Can we use local env variable in Docker file COPY command?

Tags: docker

Can I use host env variable in source part of `COPY` command in `Dockerfile`.
Eg: I have env varianle `MY_HOME = /abc/def`

Can I use following in Dockerfile?

```
COPY ${MY_HOME}/xyz.conf /ams/config/xyz.conf
```

Comment: Have you actually tried to use it ? it will be better if you explained your issue.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43473236/docker-build-arg-and-copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use environment variables like `RUN echo $HOME > /home.txt`. But be aware of the fact, that in COPY commands you can only use files that are in the [build context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/).

> The docker build command builds Docker images from a Dockerfile and a
>   “context”. A build’s context is the set of files located in the
>   specified PATH or URL. The build process can refer to any of the files
>   in the context. For example, your build can use a COPY instruction to
>   reference a file in the context.

Comment: So I can’t generate a file name using a build environment variable? For example `COPY my-file-${VERSION} .` It looks like even though the file exists in the build context (`my-file-foo` if `VERSION=foo`) the variable isn’t expanded ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy))…

Comment: I spoke too soon, see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43473236/docker-build-arg-and-copy#comment-104466815) — `ARG` is scoped to the build stage so make sure that `ARG VERSION=foo` is available in your _current_ stage!